# Does Chrome expire application cache after not being used for an extended period of time?

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, application-cache

The HTML5 spec [section on Expiring application caches](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html#expiring-application-caches) starts off with this:

> As a general rule, user agents should not expire application caches, except on request from the user, or after having been left unused for an extended period of time.

Does Chrome expire application caches after an extended period of time? If so, what is that time period?

Details about how other browsers handle this are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/webkit/browser/appcache/appcache.cc&sq=package:chromium&rcl=1377670994&l=41  Poke around there?

I don't believe Chrome does expire an appcache after a long time but I'm not at all sure.

Potentially useful: `chrome://appcache-internals/`